# SP2013: List with columns "Lookup (information already on this site)" display as URL's

Tags: lookup-column, column

I have several lists on a site that have dropdown columns that refer to other lists on the same site to keep things consistent (e.g. a department dropdown that should show the same values everywhere).  This has been working fine, and continues to work fine for other sites/lists.  But for this one, these columns are displaying as a URL (which does actually link to the department list).

This is really tough to google for, so I would be happy with an answer that at least helps define terms to make it easier to search for...

Edited to re-add a screenshot - I realized the original screenshot had internal names and phone numbers ;-)

[image]

Comment: It is hard to say what your question is. You don't want a lookup field to display value as URL? or URL is not formated the way you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar happened to me a while ago, and the solution was to modify the XSLT using SharePoint Designer:
Look for the tags that should look like this:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Applications"/>
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Project_Type"/>
```

I'm assuming that your columns are called Applications and Project_Type, please correct as needed.

Change the above code for this:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(@Applications, 'ID='), '&lt;'), '&gt;')"/>


<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(@Project_Type, 'ID='), '&lt;'), '&gt;')"/>
```

For more details, I found this helpful site: [SharePoint](http://bborole.blogspot.com/2013/04/remove-hyperlink-from-lookup-column-in.html)

I hope this helps.